# Windows Phone - How to detect what phone users have

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

For the program I'm writing, I need to detect what phone users are using my app on. Is there some function that will return the phone type?

Comment: are you needing to know phone type or just features / screen size that is available

Comment: I need either the phone type or the ppi

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN Documentation you need to be looking at the [DeviceStatus Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in the `Microsoft.Phone.Info Namespace`.

It will give you access to the:

- [DeviceName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicename%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [DeviceManufacturer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicemanufacturer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [DeviceHardwareVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicehardwareversion%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [DeviceFirmareCVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicefirmwareversion%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

<strike>to figure out the screen resolution you can look at this [MSDN Library Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247549%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)</strike>
Sorry above was for DirectX

Try looking at  [`Windows.Graphics.Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.graphics.display.aspx) Namespace's [`DisplayInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.aspx) Class to get your dpi.

Comment: Thanks! You found what I couldn't in the MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/), it is free.